# Wireshark - allow non-root user to sniff USB traffic

Tags: networking, usb, permissions, root, wireshark

I'm trying to capture data transferred across a USB connection to reverse-engineer the protocol used. I'm using wireshark to do this, which explicitly warns against running as root. So far, I've installed wireshark and run the following commands:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`
to allow members of the wireshark group (me) to access network interfaces

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap`
not sure what that does, but I think `dumpcap` was previously only executable by root.

`sudo usermod -aG wireshark (me)`
to add me to the wireshark group

This allows me to sniff network interfaces without running as root, but I still can't see the USB interfaces.

running
`gksudo wireshark`
runs wireshark as root and I *can* see usb interfaces then.

Is there a step I've missed to make USB sniffing possible for non-root users? I don't mind having to run wireshark as root for now, but it seems like I may as well set it up properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it... running

`sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE+eip /usr/bin/dumpcap`

adds the `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` property to the `dumpcap` program. This allows it to bypass the usual restriction checks for reading and writing to interface devices (if I understand it correctly)